# How to use Amplify for GraphQL API running on EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

We have GraphQL APIs that are developed with Spring Boot (Java) and deployed in an EC2 instance.

Mainly, all tutorials explain Amplify with the AppSync service where the AppSync endpoint has been used in the configuration.

However, we have GraphQL APIs without AppSync service.

How can I use the AWS Amplify service to consume GraphQL API on EC2?

Now, why Amplify service? I want to use Amplify as in near future we may migrate to AppSync service for GraphQL APIs, and during that time we don't want much change in client-side code.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/create-or-re-use-existing-backend/q/platform/js/#using-a-non-appsync-graphql-server

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for that only. I will try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you follow the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/getting-started/q/platform/js/), also activate the console [AdminUI](https://docs.amplify.aws/console/adminui/start/), it will help a lot. For queries you can checkout [DataStore](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/getting-started/q/platform/js/) as well. It is an offline/online database and last note, make sure you create the models using `aws cli` with `amplify codegen models`. Just follow the tutorial on the docs there, it's pretty straight forward.

After you have setup the CLI, you can start by doing:

```
amplify add api
```

If you activate the console I mentioned above it helps you by providing the queries, etc.